# How to Control High Voltage/Current like A/C air conditioner with Arduino?

Tags: arduino, circuit-analysis, switches, high-voltage, high-current

I need to On/Off an air conditioner with arduino. I think Relays are not suitable to handling an A/C. So experts please help me.

Comment: Why do you think relays are unsuitable? What kind of relays are you talking about? What kind of A/C are you talking about?

Comment: I'd prefer to break into the control circuits, rather than switching the AC supply - then you'd probably be switching lower voltage and current.

Comment: 2 ton split air conditioner. @wesley lee

Comment: WHY do you think you need (or want) to control high voltage/current?  Does the system not have a low-voltage thermostat control built-in?

Comment: I am using an arduino uno. Do you suggest me any switching circuit to control a 1800 watt load? @Richard Crowley

Comment: Assuming the thing was designed to have any level of control, that control is probably on the lower voltage end. In which case, that is where you would want to tie your controls into it as a well. The system may also have particular designs in place that would make high voltage control less suitable (I.E. it was designed with the assumption that it's usual environment is with the power on).

Comment: You have not shown that you NEED to "control a 1800 watt load".

Comment: How do think the existing A/C control unit turns the system on or off if not with a relay? There are relays that can switch megawatts of AC power so your little air conditioner is not a hinderance really (although relays of that size are often called "contactors" but are basically the same but bigger)

Comment: Either you do not understand how HVAC units operate (with low-voltage control circuits like thermostats), or else you have some very strange A/C unit with no control circuits.  Either way, you must explain yourself here or nobody will understand your question.

Answer (score 0):

Use a relay.  There are definitely relays that can handle switching typical air conditioners.  Relays also provide isolation between the switching logic and the switched power, which is very useful when one side is line power.